# GDAL driver.Create() TypeError

Tags: python, gdal

I have used the `osgeo.gdal` module to save numpy arrays as GeoTIFF files successfully in python for some time. Today I decided to write a simple module to handle the driver and file creation routines. Calling my module to save a numpy array gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "saveRaster.py", line 30, in <module>
    save_raster(destination,1,array,srs,gt)
File "saveRaster.py", line 10, in save_raster
    dataset_out = driver.Create(path, cols, rows, bands, dtype)
File "/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.1/Python/2.7/site-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 1440, in Create
    return _gdal.Driver_Create(self, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: in method 'Driver_Create', argument 5 of type 'int'
```

This is odd since argument 5 is the datatype argument, which should take a gdal data type such as `gdal.GDT_Float32`. However, if it try `type(gdal.GDT_Float32)` it returns `<type 'int'>`. Why then is gdal giving me a `TypeError` if an integer ought to be exactly what it is expecting?

My code is below:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

from osgeo import gdal,osr
import numpy as np

def save_raster(path, band_count, bands, srs, gt, format='GTiff', dtype=gdal.GDT_Float32):
    cols,rows = bands.shape
    # Initialize driver & create file
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName(format)
    dataset_out = driver.Create(path, cols, rows, bands, dtype)
    dataset_out.SetGeoTransform(gt)
    dataset_out.SetProjection(srs)
    # Write the array to raster bands
    for b in range(band_count):
        out_band = dataset_out.GetRasterBand(b+1)
        out_band.WriteArray(bands[b])
    # Write file to disk
    dataset_out.FlushCache()

gt = [0,1,0,0,0,-1]

srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(epsg)
srs = srs.ExportToWkt()

destination = '~/Desktop/arr.tif'

array = np.arange(0,25).reshape(5,5)

save_raster(destination,1,array,srs,gt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is a bit old, but I encountered this issue and identified the problem.

As you can see from your traceback, `driver.Create` is an API for `_gdal.Driver_Create`, which has a different sequence of arguments. When the Exception mentions `argument 5 of type 'int'` it is referring to the band count. It is likely that you had a data type that is not `'int'` for you `bands` parameter.

These types of issues have tripped me up frequently when using `numpy` and GDAL together, since the GDAL Python API has a tight control over accepted types.

Comment: Nice! Although I haven't done much work with this code in a long time, it looks like you are right. In hindsight it's very obvious: in my `save_raster` function I treated the `bands` argument as an array of shape `(bands,rows,cols)` which contained my data, but at the same time I also passed this same argument as the band number in `driver.Create`, which of course wants an integer and not an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that you are trying to pass a list in as a datatype. So perhaps change this to just be `gdal.GDT_Float32`.

Alternatively, if you have different types of data type in each band, perhaps an array comprised of values such as `[gdal.GDT_Float32,gdal.GDT_Byte]` and so on might work. Additionally, putting in just 1 doesn't throw an error, but without knowing what your other values are I can't be sure if this is right or not.

It's hard to answer accurately not knowing exactly what sort of thing you're wanting to put in for the data type.